# Transfer Strategies - Doing a Liverpool

Tags: football-manager-2012

Why is it that every guy I want to buy will only be sold for silly money, yet I seem to get list-price for my players?

Actually, that's not specifically my question; I am struggling with buying where, although I know there rightly ought to be a premium when you are buying young players who may well have a bright future, I seem to be required to pay extraordinary money for some players.

An example is a young keeper, 20 years old and currently graded with 2.5 stars and a book price of £3m. My scouts reckon a bid in excess of £10m may be required. Fair enough - If he develops reasonably well, he'll be worth that later.

So I start lower, perhaps £5m... No. An increased bid of £8m? No. Now for the kill... £12m + a %age of the sell-on fee? No, but they are willing to negotiate. They want £34m... for a guy supposed currently worth £3m (hence the Andy Carroll/Liverpool reference!)

This is just one example - there are numerous others... Curiously, regardless of the supposed value of a player, clubs frequently are willing to deal went the price breaks the £30m barrier.

I do spend time talking to the press to get positive responses from the players themselves. And I am mindful of the contract length as well.

Now the real questions: is this just the way it is, or is there a better way to approach transfers? What other factors influence the willingness of clubs to deal, and the price they will settle for? Are there any signs that indicate which deals will be acheivable?

Answer (score 3):

1st, 2nd tier teams in top 5 leagues generally overprice young talents, kind of reality nowadays.

E.g. Areola of PSG,

Try to track other leagues for investment players, young player contracts, east european players etc.

And at start of the game its always harder to buy players, track teams for unsuccessful seasons, unhappy players, lacking play times, lacking funds in clubs so that they will be eager to sell to a more reasonable prices.

Also track agent offers, they usually price for decent prices for some wonderkids.

Influencing through talks only works for high profile players for me, young talents rarely get the power to be transfer listed or so..

Comment: Playing Liverpool, I don't have the money for lots of big players so I'm trying to buy young. Also with the EPL/ECL rules, I need to have a certain number of domestic players OR young players. I do find that players offered by agents are more likely to be sold at a reasonable price, but too few are of interest.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use [Genie Scout](http://www.fmscout.com/a-fm-genie-scout-12.html) to find good players at reasonable prices.

I find having good scouts helps with this as they often suggest prices which they will sell for and the wage that the player will ask, usually within a range.

From reading other forums etc. I think the transfer market is an aspect that a lot of people want reworked in future versions.

If you have a good reputation with the other club/other manager it can help towards them accepting your bid but I'm unsure how much of an impact this has

Comment: I haven't used much it in anger yet, but I saw enough potential in Genie Scout to donate $2 to the author...

Comment: Genie Scout is probably the best way to find good players/regens and their price without editing any actual game content. I haven't donated but I've read that any donations entitle you to an upgraded version that includes more tools to find good players